# Different figsize definition in Matplotlib 2.0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have recently updated matplotlib from 1.5 to 2.0
I have noticed a difference in the definition of `figsize` parameter in `plt.subplots`:

- In matplotlib 1.5, figsize would set the dimension of the **window** generated
- In matplotlib 2.0, figsize would set the dimension of the **plot only**

So to make an example, I used to set figsize = (23, 8) that would generate a window that almost perfectly fitted the width of my screen.
Now the same parameters generate a window that exceeds the width of the screen, but if I center the window I see that the actual plot fits the window of the screen.

Is there a way to revert to previous convention, where I specify the size of the window?

Comment: The last verion of matplotlib prior to 2.0 was 1.5.3. (1.8 never existed). The figsize *always*  specifies the size of the figure and the window adjusts such that it can host the figure. If the figure is larger than the screen, the figure size is adapted such that the window fits into the screen. I am not aware of any changes that have been made here, but in any case be aware that the problem is mostly due to the fact that you chose a figsize which is larger than the screensize.

Comment: Yes, the version was 1.5, I got confused there.
Is it possible that in 2.0 by default there is more white space around the figure? I get your point that figsize was always supposed to specify the size of the window, but still there is change in behaviour for the window size.

Comment: `figsize` is always supposed to specify the size of the **figure**. What you call whitespace is part of the figure. So what happens is that the figure of some given figsize is generated. Once it's shown in a window, the window will have the size such that the figure fits in (the window around a 6 times 4 inch figure will be 6.x times 4.x inch). This is true,  unless the window would need to be larger than the screen; in this case the figure size is changed.

Comment: Okay, so there could be a wording issue in my question that I would be happy to fix. Still my problem is that given the same parameter 'figsize' I obtain a different window size passing from 1.5 to 2.0, and I would like to understand why.

Comment: The more precise your question the higher the chances that someone who is expert enough to know, takes his time to look at it. You should probably add which backend you are using and also maybe try a different backend. I personally cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case somebody had the same problem, I have found the solution looking at the matplotlib 2.0 documentation.

The change is due to a change in the default screen dpi from 80 to 100, as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#figure-size-font-size-and-screen-dpi). This had the effect (among others) of making the figure size appear bigger on the screen. (In order to mitigate this, in fact, the default figure size was reduced from 8x6 inches to 6.4x4.8 inches).

So in order to restore the same window size in matplotlib 2.0, I re-set the figure dpi to 80:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 80
```